# Haskell: NonEmpty

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and trying to see how NonEmpty works. I've written the following code.

```
module Mm (main, Bb, g) where

import Data.List.NonEmpty

g :: NonEmpty Integer -> NonEmpty Integer
g  = fmap (+9) 
main = g
```

It compiles, but when I do:

```
b= nonEmpty [2,3]
main b
```

an error shows up. I don't understand where I'm doing something wrong!

Edit: I get the following error:

```
couldn't match expected type 'NonEmpty Integer' with actual type 'Maybe 
(NonEmpty Integer)'.  In the first argument of 'main' namely 'b'.
In the expression: main b
In an equation for 'it' : it = main b
```

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: [`nonEmpty :: [a] -> Maybe (NonEmpty a)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html#v:nonEmpty), not `nonEmpty :: [a] -> (NonEmpty a)`

Comment: Do you mean I have to change function g's signature?

Comment: You'd also have to change the way it works, if you did that. There would essentially have to be two `fmap`s, or something similar.

Comment: Worth mentioning that you can directly construct `NonEmpty` using list syntax (so something just like `[2,3] :: NonEmpty Int`) by enabling `-XOverloadedLists`. The caveat is that an empty list literal results in a runtime (not compile time) error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the type of `nonEmpty`. What should the result of `nonEmpty []` be?
 You're getting a type error, because `nonEmpty` *has* to return a `Maybe (NonEmpty a)`, or it would be a partial function (possibly crashing at runtime if you ever try to access the value).

### Solution

There are a few ways to resolve the problem. One is to use `maybe` to choose an action depending on the outcome:

```
maybe (Left "List is empty") (Right . main) $ b
```

Another is to pattern match on the result, assuming it's never `Nothing`. If this assumption ever turns out to be wrong, your program will crash at runtime:

```
let (Just b) = nonEmpty [2,3] in main b
```

A third choice that I neglected to mention is to use the constructor for `NonEmpty` directly:

```
main $ 2 :| [3]
```

This is probably the solution you're looking for. The route via lists is simply an annoying detour, for the reasons I've stated above.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the second solution but it's not compiling, so I replaced b= nonEmpty [2,3] with let (Just b) = nonEmpty [2,3] in main b. Also, if we have to define all manually, then why should we use NonEmpty?

Comment: Can you provide a simple concrete example of how NonEmpty works and can be used?

Comment: Done. Have you had a look at the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.18.1/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html) btw?

Comment: You'd use `NonEmpty` whenever you need a sequence that cannot be empty. The reason you're having issues is that you were trying to convert a sequence that *can* be empty into one that cannot, without dealing with the case where the list is empty.

Comment: Much obliged :)

Comment: Also, we could do this way: main $ Data.List.NonEmpty.fromList [2,3]

Comment: Yes, that's the unsafe version of `nonEmpty`.

Comment: Again, I wouldn't recommend the route via lists.